# Python recursive inherence

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a base class that must maintain a dictionary pointing to its subclasses (so that I can instantiate them dynamically later on).

Each subclass, of course, must inherit from the base class. The problem I am facing is that, whichever I declare first, is not able find the other. Any help is appreciated?

```
class A(object):
    A_TYPES = {
        'B': B
    }

class B(A):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes already maintain a list of their subclasses, available via the `__subclasses__()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I need to have an associative list of them to able to access them by a given parameter

Comment: Just create the index after the classes have been defined

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to maintain this data inside the `A` class, but anyway...

You can add the `A_TYPES` class attribute to `A` after you've defined all the subclasses:

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass

A.A_TYPES = {'B': B, 'C': C}
```

Of course, any instances of any of these classes will be able to access (and update) `.A_TYPES`. Eg,

```
inst = C()
inst.A_TYPES.update({'F': 'fake'})
print A.A_TYPES
```

**output**

```
{'C': <class '__main__.C'>, 'B': <class '__main__.B'>, 'F': 'fake'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of all the subclasses, you can obtain an always-current list with `cls.__subsclasses__()` as @DanielRoseman wrote. You want to be able to look them up by name? No problem, just build an index yourself:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

...

A.subclass_index = dict((sub.__name__, sub) for sub in A.__subclasses__())
```

This index is static, so you should only build it after the subclasses have been defined.

In cases where only certain subclasses should be tracked, it may be appropriate to actively "register" those (sub)classes you are interested in. One way to do this is via a decorator that you apply to those subclasses you want registered. But this goes beyond what you say you need.